# Fluid Simulation Inflow Initial Velocity Graph .. not what was expected. Is clamping intentional?

Tags: fluid-simulation, graph-editor

In the image below keyframes are on the physics fluid simulation inflow initial velocity.  The numbers in the panel do not match the graph. The graph appears to have threshold clipped values.  I may not understand the intended use of the values.

What is the explanation for the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *[Normalize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html?highlight=Normalize#view-controls)* enabled. This maps the values shown in the graph editor to a relative range of -1 and 1.

Just click that blue button <kbd>Normalize</kbd> there and you will see the absolute values.

Comment: Yet another stray mouse click, of some hitherto unknown feature. ️➿.  Is there no bound to misadventures in Blender?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Well, if some features were so well hidden that you could never activate them by accident, other users who use these features might also complain about them being hidden so they didn't find them.